# tensorflow.js :TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: model, tensorflow.js

I load a model into a tensorflow.js to classify images,but it returns:
 **`"Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference", message: "Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference", number: -2146823281, stack: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter:17:131397)`**

The browser I use is chrome, and the model is gained by tensorflow in python

Here is my import

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"> </script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter">`</script>
```

Here is my code

```
<script>
        const MODEL_URL = './tensorflowjs_model.pb'
        const WEIGHTS_URL = './weights_manifest.json'
        const INPUT_NODE_NAME = 'x';
        const OUTPUT_NODE_NAME = 'prediction';
        const PREPROCESS_DIVISOR = tf.scalar(255);
      const foot=document.getElementById('foot')
        async function fun() {
        const resultElement=document.getElementById('result')
        resultElement.innerText = 'Loading MobileNet...'
      const model=await tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL)
        const pixels = tf.browser.fromPixels(foot);
        var preprocessedInput = tf.div(pixels.asType('float32'), PREPROCESS_DIVISOR);
         reshapedInput=tf.image.resizeNearestNeighbor(preprocessedInput,[28,28])
        reshapedInput=reshapedInput.reshape([-1,28,28,3])
        try{
        var output;
     output=model.predict({x:reshapedInput,keep_prob:1.0},OUTPUT_NODE_NAME)
            console.log(output)
        }
        catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        }
            console.log("hello")
    };
    fun()
```

Where I did wrong? I really need a help since the deadline is coming soon...
Thanks!

Comment: Did you have the error when converting your model or during the execution of the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely caused by the way you used `predict`

```
output=model.predict({x:reshapedInput,keep_prob:1.0},OUTPUT_NODE_NAME)
```

[predict](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.15.1/#tf.Model.predict) takes as parameter, a tensor or an array of tensors.

Since you have loaded a [frozenModel](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html), you could consider using instead `model.execute` instead.

Comment: Thank you!  You answer did help me find out my error... I did not convert 1.0 to a tensor.